# Problem Involving Finite Fields

Tags: finite-fields

I've arrived at a Theorem in text that I'm confused about:

Note: My question below is about the *statement* of this theorem, not about a proof for it.  (The proof is supplied in the text)

Theorem:  Let $E$ be a field of $p^{n}$ elements contained in an algebraic closure $\tilde{\mathbb{Z}_{p}}$ of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.  The elements of $E$ are precisely the zeros in $\tilde{\mathbb{Z}_{p}}$ of the polynomial $x^{p^{n}} - x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]$.

The first line startles me somewhat.  So far in this book we have never considered the algebraic closure of any structure which wasn't a field.  And for $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ to be a field, we must have that $p$ is prime.  This is not given in the theorem, and there was no blanket statement at the beginning of the section as there sometimes is.

My Question:  Have I missed some key fact regarding the orders of a finite field needing to be prime powers?

To give perspective to my background and where this chapter fits into development, the purpose of the chapter I am reading is to build the Galois Field of order $p^{n}$, with which I am not yet familiar.

Comment: Well, I guess the book should have said $p$ prime, since after all there is a field with $(5^3)^{17}$ elements, and $5^3$ is not prime. But the letter $p$ in field context is pretty much reserved for primes.

Comment: Assuming that you refer to Theorem $33.3$ in Fraleigh's *A First Course in Abstract Algebra*, then note that he writes in the first paragraph of Section $33$ "The purpose of this section is to determine the structure of all finite fields. We shall show that for every *prime* $p$ and positive integer $n$, there is exactly one finite field (up to isomorphism) of order $p^n\,\ldots$" (my emphasis).

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply.  Yes I am reading exactly that book and referring to exact that theorem.  I didn't draw the same conclusion from that introductory paragraph.  As someone who didn't know the fact that almost every comment refers to, for all I know it may have been required to prove some facts about fields of non-prime power order before accomplishing such a goal.  But with all these in mind, thanks for reminding me of that paragraph because now I cannot interpret it any other way.  :)

Comment: "...prove some facts about fields of non-prime power order..." Does a finite field whose order is composite but not a power of any prime exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theorem states that $E$ is a field. For a field to have $p^n$ elements, $p$ *must* be prime (unless the author is a psycho, see comments); since all finite fields have order $p^n$ for $p$ prime. So the statement that $E$ is a field of order $p^n$ already determines the fact that $p$ is prime, and so (provided this result is known) there is no need to mention that $p$ is prime in the statement of the theorem. If this is *not* a known result, then I refer you to almost any undergraduate algebra textbook which covers fields for a proof.

Comment: A field can have $p^n$ elements for $p=4$, which is not prime. (I think it may be implicit in the statement of the theorem that $p$ must be prime, simply due to the variable letter chosen for it).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I guess that's right, I think I'm just too used to the convention!

Comment: That seems totally reasonable, yet we haven't developed this fact yet.  I'll try to verify it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this answer both to satisfy myself and to address the key problem in my question.

Fact:  *A finite field must have a prime-power order*

The proof is an easy application of the immediately preceding Corollary to this theorem which I have already asked about here:  [Question about a corollary about Finite Fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177758/question-about-a-corollary-about-finite-fields/177761#177761)

Proof:  Since the preceding corollary states that *if a field has characteristic $p$, then it must have $p^n$ elements for some $n\geq 1$*, all that needs to be shown is that a field cannot have a non-prime characteristic.

If $F$ has characteristic $p$, and $p = xy$ for some $1 < x,y < p$, then $x = x\cdot 1\neq 0$ and $y = y\cdot 1\neq 0$ by definition of characteristic.  But then $xy = xy\cdot 1 = p\cdot 1 = 0$ by assumption.  Therefore $x$ and $y$ are zero divisors contained in the field $F$ which is a contradiction.

Thanks to everyone as usual for their seemingly infinite patience with my questions.